# chrome app client certificate for authentication

Tags: sockets, ssl, tcp, google-chrome-app

I am trying to find more information/documentation on submitting client certificates using a chrome application (chrome.sockets.tcp). We currently are using chrome sockets and are communicating fine using TLS 1.1. However, we have new requirements that specify using a client certificate for authentication.  I am looking for any documentation or examples that will demonstrate the implementation using chrome.sockets.tcp API. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score -1):

I believe you will need to use [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge), a JavaScript TLS implementation.

You can see an [example](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/251ada5a26d6814abc2975198e33a580596c49d5/examples/tls.js#L105) in that project's examples folder of using `getCertificate`